# To insert a Nim variable into its PCRE regex

Tags: interpolation, nim-lang

How can we insert and interpolate a Nim variable into its regex (procedure `re( ... )`) just like Perl does ?

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure why you posted this both here and on the Nim community forums. But if this comes up in someone elses search you can find my original response [here](https://forum.nim-lang.org/t/8896). The answer is as follows:

Since the `re` module and `re` procedure takes a raw string literal you can use `fmt` from `strformat` to do this:

```
import re, strformat

let
  num = r"\d*"
  wordNum = re(fmt"[a-z]\w*{num}")
  wordNum2 = re"[a-z]\w*\d*"

echo find("hello123", wordNum)
echo find("hello123", wordNum2)

echo find("       hello123", wordNum)
echo find("       hello123", wordNum2)
```

Note that the `num` string needs to be a raw literal as well, or you'd have to escape the backslash.